# Pandas pivot on one column with aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input dataframe

```
                                 Breakdown 12/31/2019 12/31/2018 12/31/2017 12/31/2016
0                             Total Assets    2926082    1997917     829758     369359
1  Total Liabilities Net Minority Interest    1771226     681684     213528      26454
2     Total Equity Gross Minority Interest    1154856    1316233     616230     342905
3                     Total Capitalization    2307673    1131101     560000     271539
4                      Common Stock Equity     813999     572080     475000     271539
```

I want to pivot on the breakdown column and have the remaining date columns become the index.
I have tried `pivot` and `pivot_table` but keep getting aggregation errors

I finally figure out a long way by

```
df = df.T
df.columns = df.loc['Breakdown']
df = df.drop('Breakdown', axis=0)
```

But i think there should be a better approach to this problem

Expected output

```
Breakdown   Total Assets  Total Liabilities Net Minority Interest  Total Equity Gross Minority Interest  Total Capitalization  Common Stock Equity
12/31/2019       2926082                                  1771226                               1154856               2307673               813999
12/31/2018       1997917                                   681684                               1316233               1131101               572080
12/31/2017        829758                                   213528                                616230                560000               475000
12/31/2016        369359                                    26454                                342905                271539               271539
```

Comment: df.set_index('Breakdown').T?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it `T`

```
df=df.set_index('Breakdown').T
```

Comment: ahh i see no pivot was needed after all

Answer (score 1):

A combination of [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) should help here: set `Breakdown` as the index, stack the remaining columns, then unstack the `Breakdown` column to get your output :

```
df.set_index("Breakdown").stack().unstack(0)
```